# Using a core data entity as an enum?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios, enums, entity-relationship

I have 2 core data entities: Question, and QuestionType. Every Question has exactly 1 QuestionType.

QuestionType has a typeName string attribute; which is primarily how I identify which QuestionType it is. It is fixed to a list of a few different types. I am wondering if it is possible to use the list of all the QuestionTypes in the data as an enum, or if not, what's the best way to use this list to assign a QuestionType to a Question, and check the QuestionType later?

Currently, when I want to assign a type to a question (based on knowing the typeName), I am doing this:

```
NSFetchRequest *questionTypeFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
questionTypeFetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"QuestionType" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *questionTypePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"typeName like %@", [questionData objectForKey:@"questionType"]];
questionTypeFetchRequest.predicate = questionTypePredicate;
question.questionType = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:questionTypeFetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This seems like a lot of work just to assign a QuestionType to my Question! And I have to repeat this for other similar entities.

And then when I want to check the QuestionType later, I am doing:

```
 if ([question.questionType.typeName isEqualToString:@"text"]){
```

This works fine, but I feel like I should be comparing the question.questionType to the specific QuestionType I am looking for, as opposed to just comparing the typeName.

Is there any way to set up an enum to hold my QuestionTypes, so that I can do this:

```
question.questionType = Text;
switch(question.questionType)
{
    case Text:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `questionType` have to be an object? If you want to use an enum, you can just declare your `questionType` property of the `Question` entity to be an integer, not another entity like `QuestionType`.

Or, you can declare your `questionType` property to be a string, and directly keep `typeName` there.

Even when you use an enum, the syntax is not like `EnumName.EnumKind` in C / Objective-C. See any textbook for the syntax.

If you keep using `questionType` as an entity, I would suggest you to cache the results of the fetch in the dictionary, as in:

```
   (QuestionType*)questionTypeWithName:(NSString*)name 
   {
        static NSMutableDictionary*dict=nil;
        if(!dict){
             dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
        }
        QuestionType*qt=[dict objectForKey:name];
        if(qt){
              return qt;
        }else{
            NSFetchRequest *questionTypeFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                ...
            NSArray*result = ... executeFetchRequest: ...
            if(result){
                  ...
                  add the resulting qt to the dict ... 
                  ...
            }else{
                  create a new QuestionType entity with a given name
                  add it to the dict.
                  return it.
            }
        }
   }
```

and something like that.

Comment: Thanks! Updated to fix the Enum syntax. It needs to be a managedObject both because the list of possible questionTypes should be able to be updated through some means other than recompiling, and because it may hold other properties aside from typeName. But I believe a static dictionary will give me what I want.

Comment: Just realized a problem with that... although this works great for setting the questionType, I don't think it would work for comparing it. question.questionType would not be the same object as my questionType that's in the dictionary; because it would be a new object fetched from CoreData. Could I implement some sort of equals: method on QuestionType to return true of the typeName is the same?

Comment: I believe it's guaranteed that one entry in the database is represented by one `NSManagedObject` inside a `MOC`, so you can just compare the pointer.  Of course if you have more than one `QuestionType` with the same `typeName`, they count as more than one object. But you shouldn't create more than one; you should always guarantee that it is unique.

Comment: I changed the code above accordingly, so that a `QuestionType` is created when necessary.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that the objects would definitely be the same. This should work well then. It will be a slight pain to implement to begin with; but it will make the code much more readable and quicker to write once it's in place. Thanks!